# Is there a config file stores the system shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings, file

We can change shortcuts in System Preferences - Keyboard - Shortcuts.

And many preferences has its associated file.

So I wonder if there is any file related to the shortcuts.

Then I can use version control or Dropbox to make it sync-able.